# How to create "Merkle Path"?

Tags: merkle-tree, merkleblock

Merkle path is always appeared in many examples relevant with verification of transaction. but they never explain how merkle path is generated.

So, I was wondering that how merkle path is generated.

I think that there are two parts.

1. Finding a block that contains requested transaction.
2. **Construct a merkle path using merkle tree that full-node has already.**

But I have no idea about second part. what is the mechanism of second part?

Sorry for my English.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the full Merkle path needed to verify a transaction?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/50674/why-is-the-full-merkle-path-needed-to-verify-a-transaction)

Comment: Never. my question is that how fullnode create Merkel path and provide it. the verification using Merkel path is not my question.